# fflib and Knowledge__kav

Tags: apex, knowledge, fflib

does anyone use ffLib with Knowledge__kav?
I am facing weird issue when using those.
When user without knowledge access fire logic and go trough centralized class that stores references to all Selectors and services it fail when mapping contains Knowledge__kav.
Even if this "Knowledge__kav.SobjectType => SEL_Knowledge.class" is not used, only stored in static map.
Error I've got is "Entity is not API accessible"

Does anyone had such problem and can propose solution?

Comment: I've seen that error when the fflib classes are at a version older than the schema requires (but I'l admit, for standard objects; I've never tried on `__kav`)

Answer (score 1):

I have assigned permission to user using permissionset and it worked for me

```
<objectPermissions>
    <allowCreate>false</allowCreate>
    <allowDelete>false</allowDelete>
    <allowEdit>false</allowEdit>
    <allowRead>true</allowRead>
    <modifyAllRecords>false</modifyAllRecords>
    <object>Knowledge__kav</object>
    <viewAllRecords>false</viewAllRecords>
</objectPermissions>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that not every User is aware of the `Knowledge__kav` object and the Users with no READ access to Knowledge will see this error whenever Apex code tries to access `Knowledge__kav.SObjectType`, not only in fflib context. The workaround is to add the Knowledge dynamically using `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`:

```
Map<String, SObjectType> dsrResults = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
if (dsrResults.containsKey('Knowledge__kav')) {
    sObjType2Selector.put(dsrResults.get('Knowledge__kav'), SEL_Knowledge.class);
}
```

Interestingly - `Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String> {'Knowledge__kav'})` throws the same error.